# booleans with constraints

Tags: c++, boolean

How do I write a boolean that checks if a string has only letters, numbers and an underscore?

Comment: What is `String`?  Did you mean `std::string` or something else?  In any case the general answer is the same, check all the characters against your conditions and if any fail return false.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I don't know how to do that. I'm new

Comment: @suitedupvet83 if you're new to programming, I recommend learning some basics programming skills in your language of choice, at least the basic ideas like loops/conditions etc, before attacking more complex problems.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `String` supports iterators, use [`all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;
return std::all_of(begin(String), end(String),
                   [](char c) { return isalnum(c) || c == '_'; });
```

Comment: nice and concise answer, +1. OPs may actually mean "only one" underscore, in which case you need to apply one more `count_if` before returning, but this is just guessing ;)

Comment: @vsoftco: could be right about the max one underscore, or perhaps it's meant to ensure exactly one underscore...?  Anyway - `count_if` is a good lead for the OP... cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In an easier way, run a loop and check all the characters holding the property you mentioned, and if not, just return false.

Code:

```
bool stringHasOnlyLettersNumbsandUndrscore(std::string const& str)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
  {
       //Your character in the string does not fulfill the property.
       if (!isalnum(str[i]) && str[i] != '_')
       {
             return false;
       }
  }
  //The whole string fulfills the condition.
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool stringHasOnlyLettersNumbsandUndrscore(std::string const& str)
{
   return ( std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(),
                           [](char c) { return isalnum(c) || c == '_'; }) &&
          (std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), 
                   [](char c) { return (c == '_'); }) < 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if each character is a letter, number or underscore.
for c and c++ , this should do.

```
 if(!isalnum(a[i]) && a[i]!='_')
 cout<<"No";
```

You will have to add < ctype > for this code to work.

This is just the quickest way that comes to mind, there might be other more complex and faster ways.